# Chrome auto launch

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extensions

Is there a way to tell what the chrome auto launcher is running?

There is a process that is eating graphical resources on Windows pro 64 bit and after poking around with sysinternals, it looks like the PID belonged to a Chrome process that didn't have a window attached to it. It looked like it may be something controlled by the auto launcher...

Disabling extensions didn't kill the process identified as causing Windows issues.

Comment: Can you please try to stop the settings in the chrome by going to settings -> system and uncheck the continue running background apps when Google chrome is closed.Analysis process usage after a machine reboot

Comment: @vembutech that might stop the applications from running at launch, but doesn't really tell me what it was doing or running; I was hoping for a way to query the application as to what it is running.

Comment: can you check it in your task manager whether any application like "Plugin Container" or "FlashPlayer_XXXXXX" consumes more RAM. If possible try disabling the java script in chrome and check whether you are facing memory shoot-up problem. Some of the website using java script for advertising, it will also consume more memory